# EF Core, Postgres call a stored procedure with a string array parameter

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I can do:

```cs
await _sensorContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("call testproc()");
```

And I can do:

```cs
System.Data.Common.DbConnection? c = _sensorContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
c.Open();
var cmd = c.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "call dewpointaverage('{\"70B3D52DD50003AC\",\"70B3D52DD5000452\"}'::varchar[])";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Which works, but I cannot figure out how to build and pass the parameter array in either (though preferably the first) approach.

There is no returned result set, the proc uses the parameters to calculate values and populate a table.

How can I pass the parameter array into either of these code examples?

Answer (score 0):

```
await this._sensorContext.Database
           .ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC StoredProcedureName @FirstParameter, @SecondParameter",
               new SqlParameter("FirstParameter", "ParameterValue"),
               new SqlParameter("SecondParameter", "SecondParameterValue"));
```

To pass an array of elements, you can create an `UserDataTable` and follow this guide to give a list to your stored procedure.

[Table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb675163(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I don't think this works, it probably does for SQL Server.  Postgres uses call rather than exec and seems to want the parameters in brackets, for example the native SQL call would be 'CALL public.dewpointaverage('{"70B3D52DD50003AC","70B3D52DD5000452"}'::varchar[]);'  If I take the simpler example I had, 'exec testproc' fails